# Button with Span and Image is not getting selected in Selenium 3.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below test case I have tried successfully,till save and let me plan works

- Go to www.triphobo.com
- Click "Later" in be updated box
- Houston in Texas
- Click on button "Plan New Trip"
- Click on "Save and Let me Plan" at the bottom of the screen

After this I get a flash screen and then the actual problem starts. I am unable to click both the options:

- Click on "Skip to Plan" at the right hand top
- Click on "Skip to Plan" again on the box

Below is my code, but Webdriver is not in a position to click. What should I do so that "Skip to Plan" can be clicked?

Below is Skip to Plan code

```
WebElement skip = waitwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//span[text()='Skip to plan ']")
));
//          action = new Actions(driver);
//          action.moveToElement(skip).perform();
//          action.click();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", skip);
WebElement skipWindow = wait
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//button[text()='Skip to Plan']")
));
skipWindow.click();
```

Error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //button[text()='Skip to Plan'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: error message ?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //button[text()='Skip to Plan'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: the problem is when you click "Save and Let me Plan"(please refer above steps in tripphobo.com) in same window another window comes, so when u run the script the moving window just goes aways so unable to find the element

Comment: I'm stuck in `Click "Later" in be updated box` step :(

Answer (score 0):

When you click Save and let me plan, it opens container/model and not new window. You do not need to switch to another window for clicking that element. Try below code :

```
WebElement skip = waitwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
    cssSelector("#js_hotel_cm_container .close-hotel-combine"))
```

It will definitely work. I have found element using CSS selector rather than xpath as it is faster(at least in my experience). You can use your xpath too by finding element by id js_hotel_cm_container, than `//span[text()='Skip to plan ']` after that.

Comment: it is not working so I have tried      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='js_close_hotel_combine']"))).click(); and it worked

Comment: now there is another problem in triphobo portal,unable to close second slider with below code -wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//div[@class='accomodation-hotel-combine-header js_ad_activity_header']")));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='global-side-drawer']//a[@id='close']"))).click();
not working please help

Comment: now i m stuck with drag and drop, for some reason its not working. Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h4[@title='Downtown Aquarium']")));
WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@title='Downtown Aquarium']"));
WebElement target=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-day-id='3']"));
builder.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@data-day-id='3']//h4[@title='Downtown Aquarium']")));